# Recovering home directory through ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, home-directory

I have Ubuntu server with ssh access. I've accidentally changed my home dir location to directory that doesn't exist. Now when I'm trying to login through ssh I saw following error:

```
Creating directory '/non/existing/directory'.
Unable to create and initialize directory '/non/existing/directory'.
```

How can I fix this

Comment: What exactly did you do to change your home dir location? Do you have root access on that machine?

Comment: Do you have physical access to the machine? If all else fails, you could use single user mode.

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov, yes, I have sudo access.

Comment: Do you have a root password? Can you ssh as root into this machine? Does scp work, can you copy files onto the machine?

Comment: First suggestion is to change your home directory back to it's previous location.  Otherwise, manually create the directory in question, including setting user and group ownership and permissions.